# How to create Private and Public subnets in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

How to create Private and Public subnets in GCP? It is not same as AWS.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/

Comment: I don't have any experience with AWS, but it seems like all the articles I read using AWS talk about  private and  public subnets, which don't seem to be constructs in GCP. I think his question is legitimate.

Answer (score 7):

When create VM , you can change external IP to none. 
This will requir NAT / LB to expose services and something like bastion server to login.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In GCP `tags` decides whether a subnet is private or public.

- For public network create `routes` in VPC section and select the next-hop to `Default Internet gateway` 
  [image]
- For private network create `routes` in VPC section and select the next-hop to `specify and instance` and select the nat instance
  [image]

Answer (score 7):

Though it's been a while since this was posted but thought to post this anyway as I ran into the same issue. I was doing a GCP-based lab challenge with an instruction to make a VPC private but I couldn't figure it out until I found this statement from an AWS doc located [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html).

> If your subnet is associated with a route table that has a route to an >internet gateway, it's known as a public subnet.

In GCP you will need to remove the default route for internet access to make the VPC private. To make machines in the VPC gain internet access to download updates for example, you will need to create a cloud NAT gateway with cloud router